# Can all android devices be rooted?

Tags: rooting, root-access

Out of curiosity, in theory can all android devices be rooted? It's my understanding that a root exploit needs to be found based on a vulnerability, and these vulnerabilities can be patched. So is it possible for a phone not to be able to be rooted?

Comment: Tough examples: Verizon variant of many devices, Blackberry phones, and the Blackphone. The latter two don't have a user base big enough to interest developers/exploiters either.

Comment: @AndyYan I didn't know blackberries could be rooted

Comment: I guess you mean like this https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LY8QV47/ref=psdc_2407749011_t2_B0169SNI3C

Comment: It's not possible to prevent someone with physical access to a device from arbitrarily modifying that device, no.  That's ultimately the same thing.

Comment: @Celeritas Nah, what I said are _negative_ examples. Anything Android from BB, including the oldest Priv, can't be rooted.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically *all* Android systems can be rooted. Rooting is, basically, introducing an `su` executable to the system, mostly done under recovery environment. The basic rooting process is simply putting an `su` under a specific directory, while advanced rooting gives a complex `su` executable as well as a GUI application for you to manage root permission management, to grant and to revoke. Besides, an engineering build of Android OS has root already enabled (stock su), so there shouldn't be an 'unrootable' Android OS.

Comment: There exist systemless root too

Comment: @Celeritas Systemless rooting is forging a `su.img` into and modify the boot image to let su mount correctly. However su still requires other stuffs (like system calls) that can't be done without a system.